# Find solution that does not satisfy the constraints?

Tags: lpsolve

I know how to find a solution that satisfies the constraints, but in my case I need to find a solution which does not satisfy the constraints. Is there anyway that `lp_solve` can do that for me?

Lets say I have the following in `LP` format:

```
max: a;
1 < a;
a < 10;
```

Then, I can use `lp_solve` to give me a solution satisfied by the constraints, but is it also possible to find a solution not satisfied by the constraints using `lp_solve`?

Comment: Couldn't you just not specify the constraints?

Comment: The problem is that I want a solution that is guaranteed not to satisfy the constraints.

Comment: Solve with and without the constraint and then remove the solutions that are in both sets?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError your idea sounds great, however the problem with lp_solve is that it only returns a single solution to the constraints (the optimal solution), it does not return all solutions. Otherwise your last suggested idea would be great.